# Can't extract ISO to USB drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, uefi

I'm trying to extract an ISO of a Linux distribution to a USB flash drive but I keep getting an error message that the destination file system does not support symlinks. The flash drive is formatted FAT32 (required for UEFI boot). If I extract the same file on a Windows PC to a USB drive everything works just fine. How come Windows can extract this file to my USB drive and Ubuntu can't?

Comment: Check out [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).  They have a good solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

The files you are trying to copy are symbolic links that just points to other files.
Your usb drive is formatted with FAT32 which do not support symbolic links, so you can not place one on the drive.

To know where the real files are open Nautilus (the file browser) right click on the file icon and select Properties, if it is a link, its Type will start with Link to, and its Link target will tell you where the real stuff is so you can copy them from their real location.

Comment: How come Windows 10 can extract the ISO image to a FAT32 flash drive? What is Windows doing differently? I'm just trying to understand what's going on behind the scenes here.

Comment: When you open your ISO in ubuntu your files are usually mounted in /media directory but you are trying to copy the symbolic links (kind of shortcuts) from another location (from the desktop i guess) ubuntu won't allow you to copy symbolic links to the drive cause FAT32 do not support this type of files.all you have to do is to find out the location where your iso is mounted and copy the files themselfs ( not the files that links to them).

Why it worked for windows ? cause you copied the real files .. imagine if you copy shortcuts like you did in ubuntu ..it would be useless.